# How to calculate height value in IE8 (box-sizing:border-box)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a jQuery plugin for doing responsive equal heights of elements. However, the script isn't working in IE8.

http://pastebin.com/LXG3hVZD

- If I hardcode the hh (heighest height) in line 58 the scripts works fine.
- If I remove box-sizing:border-box the scripts works fine.

The problem seems to be the calculation of the heighest height. I have tried using .height(), .innerHeight(), outerHeight(), and outerHeight(true) when looping through the elements, but nothing is picking up in IE8. Currently Im using innerHeight(), because regular height() does not work with box-sizing:border-box, when the elements have padding.

How do I consistently measure the height of an element in all browsers? (with box-sizing:border-box set) ?